# Remove content from nmap xml report using xml element tree parser in Python?

Tags: python, xml, nmap

Alright, I've finally sort of got walking the XML tree down, and spitting out the information I want the way I want it spat out, but now I'm trying to figure out how to modify the XML tree to cut out all the junk I don't want and overwriting the old file with the modified tree.

Doing the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('nmaptest.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for host in root.iter('host'):
   for elem in host.iter():
       if elem.tag == "extraports":
             if elem.tag['count'] == "1000":
                 print elem.attrib['count']
```

Properly spits out a bunch of 1000's from each element that has that value... If I cut out that second if statement, it puts out all the various numbers (996, 988, depending on open ports,) However, when I changed that print elem.attrib line to

```
root.remove(host)
```

it doesn't actually remove the host node/element/whatever the way I think it should... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

After you `root.remove(host)` you need to `tree.write('your.xml')` to see the changes.

```
for host in root.iter('host'):
   for elem in host.iter():
       if elem.tag == "extraports":
             if elem.tag['count'] == "1000":
                 root.remove(host)
tree.write('your.xml')` # write changes
```

Comment: I tried that too, the output document still has all the hosts still in there. You'd think that removing them from root would remove them from the above query as well, since isn't it just pulling the data from the same tree you're using to write to the document with?